# get min display brightness

Tags: android

Is there any way to get minimum display brightness value. Suppose from setting I set displaybrightnessseckbar to 0. But the android system does not make the systems brightness value to 0 rather it set it to a minimum display brightness value. this min display brightness value vary from device to device. How can I get this value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_OFF** (from the docs: indicating that the screen or button backlight brightness should be set to the lowest value when this window is in front.)

```
Window win = getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();

winParams.screenBrightness = WindowManager.LayoutParams.BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_OFF;

win.setAttributes(winParams);
```

now you can call getAtributes and look what value the Device was set to.

Comment: Window win = getWindow();
  WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
  winParams.buttonBrightness = WindowManager.LayoutParams.BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_OFF;

  win.setAttributes(winParams);  
        winParams = win.getAttributes();
  Log.i("","minimum"+winParams.screenBrightness);    I use the above code but I get -1. it is neither in 0-1 range nor in 0-255 range. Am I doing something wrong.

Comment: below 0 eg -1 is the default value, but i have a typo in my code, i (and you) set buttonBrightness. Please test it again.

Comment: this doesn't work for me ..i keep getting 0.0 as the minimum value but i believe on this phone the minimum is different. its  a LG G2.  it hink the min is 50

Comment: When I use that code, the screen goes off in some devices. Someone knows why?

Comment: @francas Using BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_OFF will set backlight brightness to the lowest value, which may appear as if it's off. After extracting the minimum brightness value, to keep the screen from appearing off the winParams.screenBrightness should be set to a higher value.

Comment: @JacobRochester the screen does not seem to be off but ti does off and does not respond anymore. It only happends in certain devices so It could be a bug.

Comment: Agreed that the screen not responding indicates the screen is off. And that this probably is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int getMinimumScreenBrightnessSetting (Context context) {
  final Resources res = Resources.getSystem();
  int id = res.getIdentifier("config_screenBrightnessSettingMinimum", "integer", "android"); // API17+
  if (id == 0)
    id = res.getIdentifier("config_screenBrightnessDim", "integer", "android"); // lower API levels
  if (id != 0) {
    try {
      return res.getInteger(id);
    }
    catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
      // ignore
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

public static int getMaximumScreenBrightnessSetting (Context context) {
  final Resources res = Resources.getSystem();
  final int id = res.getIdentifier("config_screenBrightnessSettingMaximum", "integer", "android");  // API17+
  if (id != 0) {
    try {
      return res.getInteger(id);
    }
    catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
      // ignore
    }
  }
  return 255;
}
```